# Accessing pandas cell value using df.itertuples() and column name gives AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have the following dataframe from where I want to retrieve the cell values using index and column names. The left column indicates the index values whereas the column names are from 1 to 5. This is a dummy dataframe which looks small but going forward I will be using this code to access a dataframe with 100+ columns and it is not possible to know the column names beforehand.

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t_1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| t_2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| t_3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| t_4 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

To retrieve the values from this dataframe I am using the `itertuples()` to loop over the pandas dataframe. Please note that using `iterrows()` this can be easily done but it is much slower because of which I want to avoid using that. Here is the code snippet to iterate the dataframe:

```
for row in input_df.itertuples():
    print(row.Index)
    for col in input_df.columns[1:]:
        print(row.col)
```

Since I won't be knowing the column names beforehand I want to get the column names from the dataframe list and then use it to fetch the cell values. For example, row `t_1` column 1 should return 1. However, with the above code I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'col'
```

If I mention the exact column name in place of `col` with row then I am getting the result without any error. Please help me understand what am I doing wrong here to get this error. Is there any other solution apart from `iterrows()` to get the cell value with column names?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `row[col]`?

Comment: @Ritu Use `print(getattr(row, col))` in place of `print(row.col)`.
You can also use `print(input_df.loc[row.Index, col])`

Comment: @HenryEcker I tried this but it said that the row index should be a int and not str.

Comment: Thank you @aberry, your solutions worked perfectly! Can you please suggest which one of these two: getattr, loc will be faster?

Comment: why do you need to iterate through your dataframe?

Comment: adding a little more, iteration is very rarely the right choice as it's _extremely slow_ in comparison to dedicated methods / scikit / index-based operations .. though this slowness may not matter if you only have a small amount of data (ie. if 500x as long could be fine if the total time is just 10s)

Comment: @PaulH I need to perform some operations based on index and column value of the dataframe. I understand that iterating through dataframe is not a good option but considering a matrix like data structure this is the only option I could think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change `row.col` to `getattr(row, col)`:

```py
for row in input_df.itertuples():
    print(row.Index)
    for col in input_df.columns[1:]:
        print(getattr(row, col))
```

Comment: This throws the following error:
```TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str```
My actual column names are string.

Comment: Oh, I see why. Are you using `itertuples` for a specific reason? You could iterate more simply.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I didn't realize the `itertuples` call. I edited the answer; it should work for you now. If your columns are numbers though, this won't work, because `itertuples` automatically prefixes columns that start with a digit with an underscore, so a column called `1` will be renamed to `_1` in the tuples returned by `itertuples`.

Comment: I am using itertuples for a faster solution as in future I will deal with a larger dataframe. Thank you for explaining it to me about getattr. @aberry's solution works fine in this scenario.